# Get a database connection error in a class

Tags: php, mysql

I didn't realize there was an OO way to use mysqli, so I built a class called DB. During __construct it takes the hostname, username, password, and database name. Given the following code:

```
$myDB = new DB("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
$myDBConnect = $myDB->connect();

if(!$myDBConnect) {
    echo "<strong>The following error has occurred: " . $myDB->getError();
}
```

The variable obviously contains `FALSE` because this `if` statement is currently returning `TRUE`. Here is the method from the DB class:

```
public function connect() {
    // Create connection
    $this->dbConnx = mysqli_connect($this->dbHost, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword, $this->dbName);

    if(mysqli_connect_errno($this->dbConnx)) {
        $this->dbError = mysqli_error($this->dbConnx);
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm not getting any error detail. I tried adding `or die(mysqli_error());` in the connect method, but it always just outputs the text from the file that $myDB is instantiated in. I also tried variations on the error reporting code, including having no argument in `mysqli_connect_errno()` and using `$this->dbError = mysqli_connect_error()` with and without the connection argument.

Is this needlessly complicating the OO way to use mysqli? or am I missing something simple that will allow me to move on using the code I've already got?
Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I have removed the errant $ in front of the `if` statement as per @echo_Me. It wasn't present in the actual code, just my post.

Comment: I should add that there is no error_log file being generated... it must be the way I'm trying to get the error information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you forgot the return true statement in the "connect" method?

Also you should use PDO.

Comment: Why PDO? Just because, or is there more reason?

Comment: My understanding of it is that the query returns data if successful and `false` if not. I don't believe I should have to return `true`, because I actually want the query contents in the variable after a successful call.

Comment: The method "connect" only returns false if it fails. If not, null will ne returned because every methods default return value is null. So your "if"-statement will always be true.

Comment: I think that is a good article, why you should use PDO: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/

Comment: I was mistaken about which step I was on in my previous comment - you're right; I had to return true in my own method to let the if statement know how the connect attempt went. I was thinking of the query response.

Answer (score 2):

if is not variable

```
       if(!$myDBConnect) {
      ^--remove variable sign here
```

EDIT:

your connection should be

```
    $myDB = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
```

Comment: Sorry, I must have added that by mistake - it's not present in the code.

Comment: That's working. My class was working earlier as well, I'm not sure what happened. Oh well, perhaps it was a bit redundant anyway. I'm going to do some more reading but will mark this as correct if it's what solves the issue. :) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help. The reason I picked the answer I did is because it actually addressed the problem with my current logic - I had already coded a database class and did not want to replace all of my existing code with mysqli objects, even if it is sort of redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Your `connect()` function is returning `false` on failure and nothing on success, so it will always fail the `if`. Try adding `return true;` at the end of that function.

Comment: Thanks. I've actually just removed the variable and called the connect method on its own. It was the query method result (not shown) that I wanted to do a true/false test on. My problem was brain-fry, I think. Needed to step back for a few hours.